# How to visualize colored pointclouds in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, pointcloud, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I want to show rgb values of a point cloud in rviz where I store some information inside the rgb channels. However, there is not any choice named "channel", as it is shown [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloud?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=PointCloud.png).

I've tried to add various builtin display types, such as PointCloud2, PointCloud and even LaserScan but none of them contains a channel field.

I've tried to add plugins as it is mentioned in [this question](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rviz-plugin-td914094.html#a914846). But I couldn't add any plugin via the Plugins->Manage tab of the rviz. So, I cannot obtain something like [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=manage_plugins.png).

I've checked the rviz folder in case there might be a folder named plugins or anything related to the plugins but no success.

I tried rviz --help but no information there also.

Can someone please tell me how can we do such a simple thing:) ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9597/how-to-visualize-colored-pointclouds-in-rviz?/) by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-29**:
If you want to treat an arbitrary channel in the PointCloud as an intensity value, there is a patch for that. See https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4610 . If you checkout trunk of the visualization stack and rebuild rviz, you should have access to that functionality to try it out.

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2011-03-29**:
They are in the type of pcl::PointXYZRGB and I obtain the RBG values in 24bit packaged format.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-29**:
What is the "type" of the points in the PointCloud2 you are publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the pointcloud is of type XYZRGB you should be able to select RGB8 under "Color Transformer".

---

Originally posted by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) with karma: 995 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-29**:
I think it does stand for 8 bits per channel.

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2011-03-29**:
I had tried Color Transformer with RGB, rgb and so on, but not RGB8. Thanks..Btw, does "8" in RGB8 stands for 0-255 scale(= 8bit total) or 8 bit/channel? Because as I said before, pointcloud stores 24bit color value in the rgb field.